# Why multiple vertex buffer bindings should be consecutive?

Tags: vulkan

I created a couple of vertex buffers and bindings for them:

```
VkVertexInputBindingDescription binding1{0, stride1, VK_VERTEX_INPUT_RATE_VERTEX};
VkVertexInputBindingDescription binding2{1, stride2, VK_VERTEX_INPUT_RATE_VERTEX};
```

Here you can see the consecutive 0 and 1 binding indices.

Next I record a command buffer:

```
vkCmdBindVertexBuffers(commandBuffer, 0, 1, &buffer1, &offset);
vkCmdBindVertexBuffers(commandBuffer, 1, 1, &buffer2, &offset);
```

It can be done in one call, I know, but stay with me.

Now I'm trying non-consecutive bindings:

```
VkVertexInputBindingDescription binding1{0, stride1, VK_VERTEX_INPUT_RATE_VERTEX};
VkVertexInputBindingDescription binding2{2, stride2, VK_VERTEX_INPUT_RATE_VERTEX};

vkCmdBindVertexBuffers(commandBuffer, 0, 1, &buffer1, &offset);
vkCmdBindVertexBuffers(commandBuffer, 2, 1, &buffer2, &offset);
```

Notice 0 and 2 non-consecutive binding indices.

The rendered model is indeed correct in both cases but in the second case I'm getting `validation layer: Cannot submit cmd buffer using deleted buffer 0x0.` warning. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a bug in the validation layers. They track the currently bound buffers in bindings zero through the highest binding that's been set, and when submitting a command buffer they just check that all of those bindings have valid buffers bound. But the spec only requires that bindings that are actually referenced by vertex input variables have valid buffers bound. It would be great if you could file a bug at https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-LoaderAndValidationLayers.

Comment: Thank you. I [reported an issue](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-LoaderAndValidationLayers/issues/2371).